# Unable to perform any operation on data retrieved using curl in php

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to get data from particular website. Initially I was trying to retrieve data using normal `$.ajax()` method but because of cross domain problem I drop that idea. Now I'm trying to get same data using PHP's `curl` function. I'm getting success in it, but I was expecting json response in return but I am getting some kind of json + some other string at the end of that json data. I was even trying to delete that padding with PHP's string operations but I am unable to perform any kind of operations on that data. So, is there any way of doing that? Even when I'm trying to store that `$string` variable in a log for any text file it is saving the html code not the respose posted below.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/do/mapsearch/getResults_ajax");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'city=12&map_type=listing&latlongsearch=1&encrypted_input=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzIjICB8IG11bWJhaSB8IzMjICB8IE5SSSB8IFkgIzIxI3wgIHwgMSw0LDIsMyw5MCw1LDIyIHwgMTIgfCMxIyAgfCBPLEEsQiMzIyB8IDEsNCwyLDMsOTAsNSwyMiM1IyB8IE8sQSxCICMzMSN8ICA%3D&keyword=&sortby=&mapsearch=1&locality_array=null&building_id=&latitude=19.137212294689522&longitude=72.8479625817871&latlongsearchdistance=3&page=1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);   

        $string = curl_exec($ch);

                // it's not even printing these two lines
        echo "<br /><br/><br/>";
        echo "hie";

        echo curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

                // tring to get type of response but not printing anything on web page
        echo gettype($string);


    ?>
```

Here is the part of my response:

```
{"total":2987,"resultsCount":30,"results":[{"PROP_ID":"K19962871","SPID":19962871,"VERIFIED":"N","PROFILEID":"509882","SHORTLISTED":"N","TYPE_DISP":"Apartment","AREA_UNIT":"Sq.Ft.","AREA":580,"AREA_TYPE":"Super built-up ","LOCALITY_ID":4962,"BUILDING_ID":0,"IS_XID_ATTACHED":0,"PRICE_DISP":"86 Lac","CITY":"Mumbai Andheri-Dahisar","LOCALITY":"Jogeshwari (West)","SOCIETY_NAME":"Off S.v. Road","PROP_NAME":"Off S.V. Road","LISTING":"P","BEDROOM_NUM":1,"LATITUDE":"19.1364893","LONGITUDE":"72.8488709","PROP_INFO":{"class_label":"Dealer","dealer_url":"\/sainath-estate-mumbai-andheri-dahisar-drid-509882","text":"Sainath Estate","link":true,"vcard":false},"BLDNG_INFO":{"name":"Off S.v. Road","link":null,"label":"Society :","cls":"fwn ","lcls":null},"DEFAULT_THUMB":{"url":"http:\/\/static.99acres.com\/images\/mapsearch\/nophoto.jpg","type":"noPhoto"},"MAPPED":"N","AVAILABILITY":"Ready to Move","FURNISH":""}],"encrypted_input":"UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzIjICB8IG11bWJhaSB8IzMjICB8IE5SSSB8IFkgIzIxI3wgIHwgMSw0LDIsMyw5MCw1LDIyIHwgMTIgfCMxIyAgfCBPLEEsQiMzIyB8IDEsNCwyLDMsOTAsNSwyMiM1IyB8IE8sQSxCICMxMiN8ICB8IDEgfCAxOS4xMzcyMTIyOTQ2ODk1MjIgfCA3Mi44NDc5NjI1ODE3ODcxIHwgMyAjMTQjfCAg","list_vlnk":"\/property-in-mumbai-ffid?orig_property_type=1,4,2,3,90,5,22&class=O,A,B&search_type=QS&search_location=NRI&pageid=QS&keyword_orig=mumbai&property_type=1,4,2,3,90,5,22","html2":"
```

Please any suggestions? 
Thank you..

Comment: Please also post the response you're getting.

Comment: actually response is quite large. I was thinking of posting it, but then I'll modify my question and will post a part of my response.

Comment: cool.. Thanks @Paul Crovella Now it's returning a string which I think I can handle with all PHP's string functions. :)